# C language: if() with no else(): using braces fails

Tags: c, if-statement, braces

I'm confused on need for braces after IF() expression. 
When using IF(){...}ELSE{...} I'm used to using braces around both IF and ELSE blocks. 
But when I use no ELSE block it works with no braces and fails with braces: 
works:   IF()...  
fails:   IF(){...}
Example below, this is for a microcontroller

```
#include "simpletools.h"
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    print("button = %d\n", input(3));
    if(input(3) == 1)                      //works if no braces
      high(14);
      pause(50);
      low(14);
      pause(50);
  } //while
}   // main
```

Comment: What do you mean, fails?  With no braces, only the next statement will be executed if condition is true.

Comment: Show us the "failing" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single statement follows the `if`. If you need multiple statements, they must be combined into a single *compound* statement.

```
if (input(3) == 1)
    high(14);
pause(50);
low(14);
pause(50);
```

executes both `pause` functions and `low` regardless of what `input` returns. Where you put the newlines does not affect how C parses the code. You need braces to combine the 4 function calls into a single compound statement:

```
if (input(3) == 1) {
    high(14);
    pause(50);
    low(14);
    pause(50);
}
```

The absence or presence of an `else` clause does not change anything, except that

```
if (input(3) == 1)
    high(14);
pause(50);
else ...
```

would result in an error, since the `else` is not joined to any `if` statement; the `if` concludes with the single statement `high(14)`, and the `pause(50)` is a separate statement altogether, so the `else` is out of place.

Answer (score 2):

Both the if and else clauses control only the immediately following statement. Your code, indented correctly, is actually:

```
#include "simpletools.h"
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    print("button = %d\n", input(3));
    if(input(3) == 1) 
      high(14); 
    pause(50);
    low(14);
    pause(50);
  } //while
}   // main
```

The fact that two statements may be on the same line is irrelevant; the if still only controls a single statement. If you want to control two or more statements, you must wrap them in a "compound statement" by using braces:

```
#include "simpletools.h"
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    print("button = %d\n", input(3));
    if(input(3) == 1) {
      high(14); 
      pause(50);
    } else {
      low(14);
      pause(50);
    }
  } //while
}   // main
```

Since the else must immediately follow the if's controlled statement, inserting it after your two-statement line without braces won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The way if works is `if (condition) stmt1;`; if you want more than 1 statement to be executed if the condition is true, you need to wrap them up with {}.  I suspect when you say your code "works" with no braces, you mean it compiles, but the execution will be quite different than if you wrapped the 4 statements in {}.  Recall that C doesn't give a fig about indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The identation (number of spaces or newlines) has absolutelly no meaning to the compiler. Without braces, only the very next instruction is covered by the if.

```
if (a)
    DoSomething(); DoSomethingelse();
    MoreToDo();
```

Actually means:

```
if (a)
{
    DoSomething();
}
DoSomethingelse();
MoreToDo();
```

Tipp: Always start a newline after ";", Improves readability. Some people also suggest to always use the braces, that further reduces errors such as this one.

Answer (score -1):

If `input(3)==1` then `high(14);` will be called.

But `pause(50);low(14);pause(50);` will always be executed despite the return from `input(3)`

Comment: pause(50) will not be called.

Comment: @Bart - My fault in the copy'n'paste