# else without previous if in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I understand that else statements should not have a semicolon at the end of the if statement.

The objective is to make this if/else statement work, so that if the answer is not Y or y, then to print the else statement. My question is:

- What exactly needs to be done to correct this?

Here's the code:

```
if (answer=='Y'|| 'y')
scanf(" c", &answer);
printf("\n Great! Keep listening to music. I'm sure your mood will improve.");
else printf("\n Try listening to some music that you enjoy!");
}
```

Comment: You should post code in the question, not post an image of code

Comment: You really didn't search very hard.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441560/c-language-if-with-no-else-using-braces-fails

Comment: `if (answer=='Y'|| 'y')` won’t work; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781447/can-you-use-3-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement. You also might have meant for the `scanf` format string to be `"%c"`, not `" c"`, and for it to go before the `if`. The syntax is also `if (condition) { … } else { … }`, so make those blocks. For simplicity, never omit curly braces.

Comment: Also, this program is to assist people with monitoring their mental health and mood state. It's supposed to make recommendations/suggestions on what to do to improve their mood if it is low (listen to music, call a friend; call a hotline if suicidal, etc). I

Comment: The syntax for if/else in C/C++ is that you can do away with the brace after the `if` and `else` if the the following code is just one line. in your case. `if (answer=='Y'|| 'y'){...}else ...`

Comment: @AbassSesay: Python doesn’t have braces and it doesn’t have to do with anything in this question, either.

Answer (score 1):

> The objective is to make this if/else statement work,

You are missing the curly braces in your code.

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
 if (answer=='Y'|| answer == 'y') {
     printf("\nGreat! Keep listening to music. I'm sure your mood will improve.\n");
 }
 else {
     printf("\nTry listening to some music that you enjoy!\n");
 }
```

Comment: `if (answer=='Y'|| 'y')` will always be true

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc. Thanks. Corrected it too.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what's not working now?

Comment: It didn't work. Even after entering in the correct format, and after testing the code by tying 'N' it would still print the ("Great! Keep listening to music." I'm sure your modd will improve.\n"); line instead of the ("\n Try listening to some music that you enjoy!\n"); line.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't pay attention earlier.  I just edited my answer. Try again.  Scanf goes before if statement

Comment: @VHS No cigar, sir.

Comment: If it's still not working, you need to give your full code.